# How to add a filter in react-admin List populated by unique values within the list?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Probably a newbie question, but can't quite connect the dots. I have a filter component in a List:

```
const BrandFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
      <SearchInput source="q" alwaysOn />
      <RadioButtonGroupInput source="active" alwaysOn label="" choices={[
        { id: 'true', name: 'Active' },
        { id: 'false', name: 'Inactive' },
        { id: ' ', name: 'All' },
      ]} />
      <QuickFilter source="pursue" label="Pursue" resettable />
      <SelectInput label="Status" source="status" optionText="status" />
    </Filter>
  );
```

The SelectInput doesn't show anything in the dropdown list. Not sure if it's possible but I'd like to show a dropdown list with unique status values that appear in the records. Status does not have an FK relationship; its just a text field that anything can be entered into. But, I'd still like the user to be able to see the values in the dropdown and select one. Possible? Thanks.

UPDATE

I tried to add a unique list of statuses as a reference record by modifying the api to accept a new end point: /brands/statuses and returning a unique list of statuses. It did work in populating the Status dropdown list.

App.js:

```
<Resource
  name="brands/statuses" />
```

Brand.js (Filter component)

```
  <ReferenceInput source="status" reference="brands/statuses" perPage={25}>
    <SelectInput label="Status" source="status" optionText="status" />
  </ReferenceInput>
```

However, I got an error that at least one record didn't have an id. I remembered that react expects records to have an id. So, as a hack, I added the id of the first brand record to the sql:

```
SELECT fpb.id, fpb.status FROM lookabout.fgm_product_brand fpb WHERE fpb.status IS NOT NULL GROUP BY fpb.status ORDER BY fpb.status
```

That resulted in getting a list of statuses in the filter dropdown. However, when I clicked on one of them, it sent the id of the status (which was actually just the id of a brand record) and returned no results:

```
http://localhost:3010/brands/find?limit=15&page=1&orderBy=id&orderDir=ASC&filter={%22active%22:%22%20%22,%22status%22:2}
```

Close, but not quite. I feel I'm forcing something because I'm not quite getting it. Or, working against how react-admin was meant to operate?? Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.

FINAL UPDATE

Got it to work. Rather than use the id of the brand record as a substitute status id, I just used the status itself. So, the sql in the api now reads:

```
SELECT fpb.status AS id, fpb.status FROM lookabout.fgm_product_brand fpb WHERE fpb.status IS NOT NULL GROUP BY fpb.status ORDER BY fpb.status
```

That gives the result set an id that is unique and that is then used in when passing the filter criteria. The HTTP GET request now looks like:

```
http://localhost:3010/brands/find?limit=15&page=1&orderBy=id&orderDir=ASC&filter={%22active%22:%22%20%22,%22status%22:%22Potential%22}
```

And that returns the expected results. Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: The values present only in the given list page or on all records?

Comment: In all records. I see how ReferenceInput works; sends a call to the api to get the list of items (I think that's how it works). Thought it might work similarly with any field. Or, do I need to call the api as well? Thanks.

Comment: You are right. That's how ReferenceInput works. I've added a answer with possible solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions:

First, probably the best but with more work, is create new api endpoint, e.g, yourResourceStatuses or yourResource/statuses, which returns distinct uniques values for the status field, then reference this new resource with a ReferenceInput as your SelectInput parent:

```
<Filter>
    ....
    <ReferenceInput source="status" reference="resourceStatuses">
        <SelectInput label="Status" source="status" optionText="status" />
    </ReferenceInput>
<Filter/>
```

You need also to declare such resource under Admin, only with name prop, allowing react-admin to initialize it's redux stores.

```
<Admin>
    ....
    <Resource name="resourceStatuses"/>
</Admin>
```

If you are using SQL, this can be as simple as

```
SELECT DISTINCT status from 'table';
```

The second, probably will make appear duplicate status values on the dropdown, but would require less work if your api support text search on the status field. Is chaging the SelectInput for a AutocompleteInput and wrapping it with a ReferenceInput with the same resource.

```
<Filter>
    ....
    <ReferenceInput
        source="status"
        reference="yourResource"
        filterToQuery={searchText => ({ status: searchText })}
    >
        <AutocompleteInput label="Status" optionText="status" />
    </ReferenceInput>
<Filter/>
```

Comment: I like the first option. Since I have control of the API, that seems like the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this and got part way there. The list of status do appear in the filter. Thanks for that. However, when I first tried it by returning just the list of unique statuses, I got an error that said at least one record didn't have an id. So, in my sql, I included an id from the brands table and then grouped by status, which did give me a list of unique statuses without the id error. But, when I select a status in the filter dropdown, nothing returns, because it's sending status:id in the filter for brands rather than status:<selected status>. Does that make sense? See question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried wrapping it with a `<ReferenceInput />` component? Otherwise it appears you have to define select options.

According to the docs, wrapping it with ReferenceInput should pull the options automatically based on source:

---

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#selectinput

Scroll to the end of the text referencing SelectInput and you'll see this:

---

Tip: If you want to populate the choices attribute with a list of related records, you should decorate `<SelectInput> with <ReferenceInput>`, and leave the choices empty:

```
import { SelectInput, ReferenceInput } from 'react-admin';

    <ReferenceInput label="Author" source="author_id" reference="authors">
        <SelectInput optionText="last_name" />
    </ReferenceInput>
```

---

If that doesn't work, maybe you can fetch the data and define your options from there. For reference:

```
<SelectInput source="category" allowEmpty emptyValue={null} choices={[
    { id: 'programming', name: 'Programming' },
    { id: 'lifestyle', name: 'Lifestyle' },
    { id: 'photography', name: 'Photography' },
]} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think your first suggestion is similar to the accepted answer, but gstvg's was a bit more complete and specific to my situation.